# Prove that the following is true or provide a counterexample if it is false

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For all integers a, b, and c: If a|b and a|c then a|(b − c).
I think this is true and so for it's proof I have:
Since a|b then b=ak for some k in integers
Since a|c then c=al for some l in integers
I must show that b-c can be written as a * some integer
then b-c would be ak-al = a(k-l)
and since integers are closed under subtraction k-1 is an integer
And so I have shown b-c to be a*some integer

My friend says this is false if a,b and c are the same numbers because then you would end up with a|0 which he says is not true. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with $a\mid 0$, by the way.

Comment: Indeed, $a \mid 0$, since you can find an integer $k$ so that $a \cdot k = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would show it:

I would prove the more general case that **if a|b and a|c then a|bs + ct**, meaning that a divides any linear combination of b and c.

Proof:
Suppose $a|b$ and $a|c$ 
Then there are integers d and e such that $${ad = b}$$ and $${ae = c}$$ 
Multiplying the first equation by s and the second equation by t gives 
 $$ads = bs$$ and $$aet = ct$$
Adding these two equations yields $$ads + aet = bs + ct$$ 
Factoring out an a on the left hand side gives $$a(ds + et) = bs + ct$$
Since ds + et is an integer, $$a|bs + ct$$

Since we showed this for any integers s and t, have a look at some special cases:

- If we let t = s = 1, we see that **a|b+c**
- If we let t = -1 and s = 1, we
  see that **a|b-c**

I hope that helps :)